# JavaFX 2.2 How to setLowerBound and setUpperBound in DateAxis in LineChart generated by FXML

Tags: date, javafx, fxml

I have whit JavaFX Scene builder made layout for my application. On my linechart I drow some graphs depending on dates. By default JavaFX LineChart doesn't support dates. So I use this librariy http://myjavafx.blogspot.com/2013/09/javafx-charts-display-date-values-on.html and it works fine.
Librray also allows setLowerBound and setUpperBound methods. I havev wrote code bit it doesn't work.

My FXML code (ONLY FOR LINECHART):

```
 <LineChart fx:id="lineChart" animated="false">
    <xAxis>
       <DateAxis side="BOTTOM" label="Napoved kalibracije" fx:id="dateAxis"/>
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis >
       <NumberAxis label="Odstopanja v %" lowerBound="0" upperBound="95" tickUnit="10"/>
    </yAxis>
 </LineChart>
```

As you can see I have set id="dateAxis" so I can refer from main class to layout crate as I mentioned by Scene Builder.

Code in main class(ONLY FOR DATAAXIS) wher I get ID form FXML:

```
 Scene scena = primaryStage.getScene();
 DateAxis dA = (DateAxis) scena.lookup("#dateAxis");
 dA.setUpperBound(new GregorianCalendar(2016,8,23).getTime());
 primaryStage.show(); 

 System.out.println(dA);
```

returns:

```
 DateAxis[id=dateAxis, styleClass=axis]
```

what means that is working fine. But my chart on xAxis(DateAxis) doesn't go to 23th of August 2016.
I would be very grateful if we solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two changes you need to apply, The first is to add  the constructor of the date axis, two arguments:  lower bound + upper bound,
example:

```
 final DateAxis xAxis = new DateAxis(new Date(2013-1900,1,4),new Date(2013-1900,30,14));
```

The other change is to change the source code of class DateAxis , look for this part of the code (just search for "true" to find the specific line )

```
public DateAxis(Date lowerBound, Date upperBound) {
        this();
        setAutoRanging(true); // change it to "false" 
        setLowerBound(lowerBound);
        setUpperBound(upperBound);
    }
```

and change the "setAutoRanging" argument to "false"